# Convergence of quotient involving sum of odd factorials

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Consider
$$
a_N = \frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots +N!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+N!}
$$

I need to prove that $\limsup_{N\to\infty}a_N=1$ and $\liminf_{N\to\infty}a_N=0$. I think it depends on taking a subsequence of odd values of $N$ to prove the first equality, and one of even values of $N$ to prove the second. I have tried to relate the two sums but my problem is that there is not a simple expression for the sum of the factorials of the first $N$ natural numbers.

Comment: Your formula for the numerator is incorrect when $N$ is even.

Comment: Yes, i'm obviously abusing notation. The summation on the numerator is over odd numbers up to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that each $a_n \in [0,1]$, so the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are also in this interval (in particular exist/are finite). Now, $$1!+2+ \dots + (N−2)! \le (N−2)(N−2)! \le (N−1)!,$$
so for $N$ odd,
$$a_n = \frac{1! + 3! + \dots + (N-2)! + N!}{1! + \dots + (N-2)! + (N-1)! + N!} \ge \frac{N!}{2(N-1)! + N!} = \frac{N}{N + 2} \to 1,$$
which implies that $\limsup a_n = 1$. Similarly for $N$ even,
$$a_N = \frac{1! + 3! + \dots + (N-3)! + (N-1)!}{1! + \dots + (N-2)! + (N-1)! + N!} \le \frac{2(N-1)!}{N!} = \frac{2}{N} \to 0,$$
so $\liminf a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If N is even this is acctually: 
$\frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+N!}\leq\frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!}{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!+4(1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!)-4\cdot1!+2!}$

And when $N\to\infty$ this $\to\frac{1}{5}$.

But of course there is nothing special about 4. you can also factor k out and subtract a finite sum:
$\frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+N!}\leq\frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!}{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!+(2k)(1!+3!+5!+\cdots+(N-1)!)-(2k)(1!+3!+\ldots+(2k-1)!)+2!+4!+6!+\ldots+(2k-2)!}$

which approaches $\frac{1}{2k+1}$ as $N\to\infty$. So this sequence goes to 0.

If $N\geq3$ is odd let's prove by induction that:
$1!+2!+\ldots(N-2)!+(N-1)!\leq\frac{2}{N}N!$

Base:
$1!+2!=3\leq\frac{2}{3}\cdot6$

Step:
$1!+2!+\ldots(N-2)!+(N-1)!\leq\frac{2}{N-1}(N-1)!+(N-1)!=\frac{N+1}{(N-1)N}(N)!\leq\frac{2}{N}N!$

The last inequality requires $N\geq3$ (left as an exercise).

So:
$\frac{1!+3!+5!+\cdots+N!}{1!+2!+3!+\cdots+N!}\geq\frac{N!}{\frac{2}{N}N!+N!}=\frac{N}{N+2}\to1$

Of course all elements are between 0 and 1 so this are the lim sup and lim inf.